# How to find unique values by group in datatable Frame

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have created a datatable frame as follows,

```py
DT_EX = dt.Frame({'cid':[1,2,1,2,3,2,4,2,4,5],
                  'cust_life_cycle':['Lead','Active','Lead','Active','Inactive','Lead','Active','Lead','Inactive','Lead']})
```

Here I have three unique customer life cycles and each of these counts are found as

```
DT_EX[:, count(), by(f.cust_life_cycle)]
```

Along with it, I have five customer IDs and these counts are as

```
DT_EX[:, count(), by(f.cid)]
```

Now I would like to see how many of unique customer ID's existed per each of customer life cycle,

```
DT_EX[:, {'unique_cids':dt.unique(f.cid)}, by(f.cust_life_cycle)]
```

It should display as Lead customer has got 3 unique customer ID's such as (1,2,5), Active user has got 2 unique customer ID's (2,4) so on forth.

I couldn't get it as expected, Could you please let me know how to get it fixed?.

FYI: I have tried to reproduce the same on R data.table frame, its working.

```
DT_EX[, uniqueN(cid), by=cust_life_cycle]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a [nunique](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dt/nunique.html) implementation :

```py
DT_EX[:, f.cid.nunique(), 'cust_life_cycle']

   | cust_life_cycle    cid
   | str32            int64
-- + ---------------  -----
 0 | Active               2
 1 | Inactive             2
 2 | Lead                 3
[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 6):

The `dt.unique` function does not apply by groups (yet). So, one way to achieve what you need would be to first group by the lifecycle + customerID, and then in the second step re-group by lifecycle only:

```
>>> DT_EX[:, count(), by(f.cust_life_cycle, f.cid)]\
...      [:, {"unique_cids": count()}, by(f.cust_life_cycle)]

   | cust_life_cycle  unique_cids
-- + ---------------  -----------
 0 | Active                     2
 1 | Inactive                   2
 2 | Lead                       3

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

@pasha

I have also created a custom function for my practice as below,

```
def pydt_unique_per_group(DT,by_col,uni_col):
    DT_dict = DT[:,(f[by_col],f[uni_col])].to_dict()
    pairs = list(zip(DT_dict[by_col], DT_dict[uni_col]))
    unique_per_col_dict = {k : list(map(itemgetter(1), v)) for k,v in groupby(sorted(pairs, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))}
    unique_per_col_count = {drink:len(set(ingr)) for drink,ingr in unique_per_col_dict.items()}
    unique_per_col_count_sort = {k:v for k,v in sorted(unique_per_col_count.items(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)}
    by_group_summary_dict = {by_col:[],'count':[]}
    for k, v in unique_per_col_count_sort.items():
        by_group_summary_dict[by_col].append(k)
        by_group_summary_dict['count'].append(v)
    return dt.Frame(by_group_summary_dict)
```

output:

```
In [8]: pydt_unique_per_group(DT_EX,'cust_life_cycle','cid')                                                                                                                                                
Out[8]: 
   | cust_life_cycle  count
-- + ---------------  -----
 0 | Lead                 3
 1 | Active               2
 2 | Inactive             2

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```